# Show a battery notification with a BLE device

Tags: ios, bluetooth-lowenergy

Is it possible to add another device to the batteries widget?

[image: Battery widget]

The device is *not* an headset, and it will be connected via BLE exclusively.

Is there anything that can be done in my application or on the device itself to support this?

Possibly related:

- [Bluetooth Design Guidelines (section 5)](https://developer.apple.com/hardwaredrivers/BluetoothDesignGuidelines.pdf)

Comment: I don't think that it would work, but at least, if you want to give battery level of your BLE device, please conforms to official service/characteristic: https://developer.bluetooth.org/gatt/services/Pages/ServiceViewer.aspx?u=org.bluetooth.service.battery_service.xml

Comment: You would have to create your own extension. You can't add batteries to the iOS batteries extensiin

Comment: @Paulw11 that I feared, but do you have any source?

Comment: There are lots of things that you can't do that don't have some document that says "you can't do this". In those cases, as in this, you have to be guided by the documentation that says what you can do. You can't find any documentation that explains how to add an arbitrary battery level and you can't find any documentation that explains how to modify an existing today extension that isn't part of your app because these things can't be done. You *can* find a document that explains how a legacy Bluetooth device, such as a headset, can report battery level to iOS.

Comment: @Paulw11 thanks, care to write an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: guys any good answer for this ??